# Vue store undefined when component has custom constructor

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

When I try to include a custom constructor in my vue component that accesses the vuex store in some other function I get a runtime error. The store is undefined at the time the component is created.

I suspect that, by adding a custom constructor the component is created before the store is initialized. I can work around this by importing another component to this respective component which I guess ques the creation after the store initialization.

```js
export default class myComponent extends Vue {
    myVal: myType[] = this.$store.getters.getVal;

    constructor(){
        //call Vue constructor
        super();
        //do Stuff
    } 

}
```

With this setup I get the error.
*Cannot read property 'state' of undefined*

If I include another component this somehow works.

```
import anotherComponent from "./AnotherComponent.vue";

@Component({
    components: {
        anotherComponent
    }
})

export default class myComponent extends Vue {
...
}
```

When I set it up without a custom constructor it also works.

I would like to understand how I can create a component with a constructor and also access the store in the same component without having to import some not needed other dependency. I guess I am missing something crucial but unfortunately I can not figure it out. Vue + Typescript does not seem to be a popular combination despite I like it quite well up to now.

Glad for any input on this.

Comment: Why you need constructor? Maybe better to use `created` hook?

Comment: Good point, unfortunately I have exactly the same issue with the lifecycle hooks. They only work if I import another component before. I thought if I figure out how to set up the constructor I also solve the other issue.

Comment: In the version without a child component, do you have the annotation `@Component` before the `class`?

Comment: No of course not. This probably got lost somewhere. I guess I didn't see the wood for trees. Thank you guys, this solved the issue!

Comment: @Alexander thanks. I couldn't see a reason why the constructor is not working. I'm just importing another TS class and generating an instance inside the constructor. Though I see that it enters inside constructor, it somehow does not generate my object. When I used the hook `created` it is fine now.